# Unable to start sonarqube java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have installed sonarqube 7.7 on windows 10 but when I'm trying to start the sonarqube server using the StartSonar.bat file It is giving me the following **error**

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32000.
jvm 1    | java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
jvm 1    | Exiting JVM...
wrapper  | Startup failed: Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM.
wrapper  | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
wrapper  | JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is how my **wrapper.conf** looks like

```
# Path to JVM executable. By default it must be available in PATH.
# Can be an absolute path, for example:
#wrapper.java.command=/path/to/my/jdk/bin/java
wrapper.java.command=java


#
# DO NOT EDIT THE FOLLOWING SECTIONS
#


#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java
#********************************************************************
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dsonar.wrapped=true
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.awt.headless=true
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../../lib/jsw/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../../lib/common/*.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../../lib/*.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=./lib
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.sonar.application.App
wrapper.java.initmemory=8
wrapper.java.maxmemory=32

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logs
#********************************************************************

wrapper.console.format=PM
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile=../../logs/sonar.log
wrapper.logfile.format=M
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
#wrapper.logfile.maxsize=0

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
#wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=0

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows Properties
#********************************************************************
# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=SonarQube

# Disallow start of multiple instances of an application at the same time on Windows
wrapper.single_invocation=true

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name=SonarQube

# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=SonarQube

# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description=SonarQube

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false

#********************************************************************
# Forking Properties
#********************************************************************
wrapper.disable_restarts=TRUE
wrapper.ping.timeout=0
wrapper.shutdown.timeout=300
wrapper.jvm_exit.timeout=300
```

This is how my **sonar.log** file looks like

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Failed to connect to the Wrapper at port 32000.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
Exiting JVM...
Startup failed: Timed out waiting for a signal from the JVM.
JVM did not exit on request, terminated
JVM Restarts disabled.  Shutting down.
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

My Java version is

```
java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
```

I'm not able to figure out what is going wrong. Please help

Comment: The port could be already used. Try running `netstat`

Answer (score 0):

Please off the firewall and launch again StartSonar.bat

Comment: It's better to send this as a comment or provide more information on your answer.